# Java byte/bit trouble

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class Main {

  public static int gyro_out_X, gyro_out_Y, gyro_out_Z, acc_out_X, acc_out_Y, acc_out_Z, adc_pressure, HMC_xo, HMC_yo, HMC_zo;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //In the constructor pass the name of the port with which we work
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");
    try {

        //Open port
        serialPort.openPort();
        //We expose the settings. You can also use this line - serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
        serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_115200,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        while (1 == 1) {

            byte[] sensor_buffer = serialPort.readBytes(21);
            gyro_out_X = ((sensor_buffer[1] << 8) + sensor_buffer[2]);
            gyro_out_Y = ((sensor_buffer[3] << 8) + sensor_buffer[4]);
            gyro_out_Z = ((sensor_buffer[5] << 8) + sensor_buffer[6]);
            acc_out_X = ((sensor_buffer[7] << 8) + sensor_buffer[8]);
            acc_out_Y = ((sensor_buffer[9] << 8) + sensor_buffer[10]);
            acc_out_Z = ((sensor_buffer[11] << 8) + sensor_buffer[12]);
            HMC_xo = ((sensor_buffer[13] << 8) + sensor_buffer[14]);
            HMC_yo = ((sensor_buffer[15] << 8) + sensor_buffer[16]);
            HMC_zo = ((sensor_buffer[17] << 8) + sensor_buffer[18]);

            System.out.println("gyro_out_X: " + gyro_out_X );

            //Closing the port
            //  serialPort.closePort();
        }
    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

OK, in this construction I read 21 byte of code, 1 byte go to <<8 bits, and then I plus another byte, what gives me values from -255 to 255.

But in output I see:

```
 gyro_out_X: 14556
 gyro_out_X: 23857
 gyro_out_X: -15234
 gyro_out_X: -255
 gyro_out_X: 23295
 gyro_out_X: -13346
 gyro_out_X: -255
 gyro_out_X: 30813
 gyro_out_X: 12506
 gyro_out_X: -255
 gyro_out_X: 5104
 gyro_out_X: -10220
 gyro_out_X: 23807
 gyro_out_X: 5246
 gyro_out_X: -463
 gyro_out_X: -27536
 gyro_out_X: -511
 gyro_out_X: -8640
 gyro_out_X: 4306
 gyro_out_X: 16448
 gyro_out_X: 21075
 gyro_out_X: 16450
 gyro_out_X: 220
 gyro_out_X: 16448
```

Data sent every 10 ms.

What I do wrong?

Comment: 23857 and -13346  not in -255 +255 set. What I do wrong?

Comment: Do you want to fit a 2-byte value into the `[-255..+255]` range? Have you examined the `sensor_buffer` contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking two byte (8 bits) values, and create a "short" (16 bits) value. A 16-bit signed value can be from -32768 to 32767. The only way you can get a value between -255 and 255 is for whatever program sends the data sends the correct bits.

Answer (score 0):

This will reconstruct a 16bit value out of two 8bit values. Though 16bit will give you more than [-255,255]. Depending on your endinaness you will have to swap `ub1` and `ub2` (`gyro_out_x = (ub1 << 8) + ub1;`).

```
int ub1 = outByte[1] & 0xFF;
int ub2 = outByte[2] & 0xFF;
gyro_out_x = (ub2 << 8) + ub1;
```

Also, are you sure that your values begin at outByte[1]? Isn't it like this:

- outByte[0] and outByte[1] -> gyro_out_x
- outByte[2] and outByte[3] -> gyro_out_y
- etc?